# Neo4j cypher keeping track of delete Nodes/relationships

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

When I delete a Node, Relationship in Java executing Cypher:

```
MATCH (n { name: 'Andres' })-[r]-() DELETE n, r
```

or

```
DELETE (n) where id(n)=3;
```

is there a way to keep track of the Nodes, Relationships I've deleted?
Getting the Id or the Object(Node/Rs).

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [transaction event handler](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/transactions-events.html)

Or something like this [change-feed extension](http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2014/08/27/graphaware-neo4j-changefeed.html)

In general cypher can return statistics about the number of deleted entities in `result.getQueryStatistics()`

Comment: The Transaction event handler does not return any result for cypher queries executed in his context also I do need the results independently of the success of the transaction.